# Using Widgets IN Android

Tags: android-widget

I'm new to Android. I want to take input from user and display on it screen. Is anyone help to me.. And also give me explanation also, that help me to understand.. Please help me..

Thanks In Advance...

Snehal Choudhari..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html